# Convert DF into Numpy Array for calculations

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dataframe, toarray

I have the data in a dataframe format that I will use for linear regression calculation using user-built function. Here is the code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
boston = load_boston()

bos = pd.DataFrame(boston.data) # convert to DF
bos.columns = boston.feature_names
bos['PRICE'] = boston.target
y = bos.PRICE
x = bos.drop('PRICE', axis = 1)  # DROP PRICE since only want X-type variables (not Y-target)

xw = df.to_array(x)

xw = np.insert(xw,0,1, axis = 1) # to insert a column of "1" values
```

However, I am getting the error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-131-272f1b4d26ba> in <module>()
  1 import copy
  2 
----> 3 xw = df.to_array(x)

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'to_array'
```

I am not sure where the problem. I need to pass an array of values (x in this case) to the function to execute some matrix operations

The insert function was working in a step by step code development but for some reason is failing here.

I tried:

```
xw = copy.deepcopy(x)
```

with no success

Any thoughts?

Comment: I even checked the type after conversion (type(xw) and it gave me np.ndarray as a type. Not sure where the problem

Comment: Do `type(x)`, what do you get? Or possibly include a printout of `x`

Comment: I think I got it somehow. Not sure but what is working:   xw = copy.deepcopy(x)
xw = np.c_[np.ones(lnY), xw]  Not sure this works (inserting a first column of "1" and the other way did not but here the result (lnY is the size of a target array (Y values)

Comment: What is `df`? It's not defined anywhere, but appears to be an `int`. Do you mean `x.as_matrix()`?

Answer (score 0):

it is `x.as_matrix()` not `df.to_array(x)` 
Please refer to pandas document for more detail on [as_matrix()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html)

Here is the code that work

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

boston = load_boston()

bos = pd.DataFrame(boston.data) # convert to DF
bos.columns = boston.feature_names
bos['PRICE'] = boston.target
y = bos.PRICE
x = bos.drop('PRICE', axis = 1)  # DROP PRICE since only want X-type variables (not Y-target)

xw = x.as_matrix()

xw = np.insert(xw,0,1, axis = 1) # to insert a column of "1" values
```